# Scaffolding for Play Framework 2

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Is there scaffolding generator utility for Play Framework 2 for Scala like Ruby on Rails has? I found some topics about this but didn't figure out which one was most popular or even if there was the standard one?

Your thoughts?

**UPDATE**: I mean scaffolding for generating controllers, views, models or any of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MongoDB, the reactive mongo plugin has an auto source feature, which gives you a REST scaffolding API:

http://mandubian.com/2013/06/11/play-autosource/

Answer (score 0):

Slick can generate models from your database tables. They aren't play specific so I think you'd have to write controllers yourself, but it's a start.

https://scala-slick.org/